# How to get a value from a api response dynamic endpoint?

Tags: json, reactjs, api, endpoint, jsonresponse

I have API responses which are like res.data.url.full,res.data.url.small and res.data.url.raw and i have a custom value like val="small"..so how can i obtain the res.data.url.small by using this custom val? Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this would solve your problem.Use if else for all the three cases

```
if(val=="small")
{
 res.data.url.small
}
```

and in the same way use all the other cases